# Efficient algorithm for determining if $\pm c_1 \pm c_2 \dots \pm c_n = 0$

Tags: algorithms, decision-problem

> Suppose that we're given $n$ integers $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n$. We want
>   to know if there is any assignment of $+$ and $-$ signs such that
>
> $$ \pm c_1 \pm c_2 \dots \pm c_n = 0. $$

Does anyone know of a polynomial-time way to do this? Since there are $n$ integers, there are $2^n$ assignments of signs to consider, which grows rather quickly.

I've tried to phrase this problem in such a way that I can make use of dynamic programming, but DP usually lends itself to optimization sorts of problems, and this problem does not fall into that category (at least as stated).

Comment: There are pseudo-polynomial time algorithm (using DP)  on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), time complexity $O(nS)$, where $S=\sum{c_i}$. Check your constraint to see if it meets your requirement.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: This is just the well-known NP-complete problem PARTITION.

Comment: I think this is so close to a complete answer that you don't need the word "Hint". :-)

Comment: and include the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem